# Embedding/Encoding IMG src as Base64 at Request Time in C#

Tags: c#, image, base64

I have an ASP.NET CMS which uses a Telerik HTML Editor. It creates clean Typical HTML. Image tags are typically relative (although someone could add absolute -- if they wanted).

I now want to serve the HTML -- but Embed all the Image data into the HTML using Base64 URI.
(Example: `<img src="data:image/gif;base64, jdjdheueofkfl...">`)
All on the Fly.

Server-Side using C#

I'm guessing:

- Parse HTML for IMG tags
- For Each - Load File, ConvertBase64, Rewrite SRC
- Serve String

Question is:

Am I missing some simple c# `EncoderAsEmbededBase64(strHTML)` function that would convert HTML with Links to HTML Embedded?

Comment: This question is nothing to do with embedded programming, see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse Html i recommend use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
after parsing the html you can do next operations